# Pipeline of Interceptor by castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, interceptor, pipeline

I want to make a pipeline of Interceptors on a class named A. By pipleline i means each of those interceptor may do some processes before or after the class method invoked without calling the intercepted method directly, unlike traditional usage of interceptors in Windsor. Suppose the following example which I want to apply two interceptors Interceptor1 and Interceptor2 on all the class A methods. In futures others,maybe, other kind of interceptor will be added. provide that the order of these interceptors are not important, who should call the invocation.Proceed, where the intercepted method calling should happen.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
public class Interceptor1 : IInterceptor
{
    public virtual void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {

    }
}

public class Interceptor2 : IInterceptor
{
    public virtual void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {

    }
}
```

As an example suppose we want to check security, start transaction or something like these before entring the a class method. It should be mentioned that these interceptors are different for each class and might be changed during the development process.
We can see such pattern in wcf where we use operation behavior or service behavior to have control over the entire service or each service operation.

Answer (score 0):

I must be an old school Castle guy, but isn't that what a Factory is for?  Slap an interface on each class, and let the factory work on that interface.

Comment: the problem is not how to construct an interface or interceptor, the main reason that usually lead us to use Factories. The problem is how to arrange and manage interceptors in order to do some processing before or after the class methods.

Comment: Right, which I feel this is a bad place to put it because it is not easily discoverable.  It's why I stay away from custom IoC registrations like this, and create DDD-like factories to handle my object creations - read: place your before and after `processing` in the factory's `Create()` method following standard coding practices.  It's very discoverable, follows enterprise patterns, and easy to read.  Then I register the factory in the IoC for that complex object.

Comment: And if you come up with a sistuation that you need to do it with Interceptors because you have to access your IoC's kernel/core to execute some other core IoC function - i'd say you should step back and re-examine the structure of your code, if you are relying on the IoC to instantiate of your objects.